# Easy way to copy the name of the SF Symbols app symbol?

Tags: macos, sf-symbols

Is there really no way to easily copy the label? Am I missing a shortcut? Specifically, looking for an easy & quick way to copy the `square.and.arrow.up`. I know this sounds lazy, but hey, I do this a lot, finding a quick way would save me a lot of time!

Command + C just copied the unicode same as dragging and dropping.

```
Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
    .font(.system(size: 27, weight: .medium))
    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
```

[image]

Comment: ⇧⌘C doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! **⇧⌘C** If you forget it, go to Edit → Copy Name.

[image]